Issue when displaying a dropdown list in Symfony
Am using the following code in order to display a dropdown list from a mariadb database table, however it does not work when testing and it :
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Signal;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class SignalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('actionPlan')
            ->add('actionPlanStatus', StatusType::class, [
                'class' => Status::class,
                'mapped' => false,
                'choise_label' => function(Post $post){
                    return $post->getName();
                }
                 ])
            ->add('deadline')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Signal::class,
        ]);
    }
}

I get the following error.
An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "App\Form\StatusType": The options "choise_label", "class" do not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "form_attr", "getter", "help", "help_attr", "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "is_empty_callback", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_html", "label_translation_parameters", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "priority", "property_path", "required", "row_attr", "setter", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".
Can you please help me unlocking this situation.

choise_label (sic) should be choice_label (s->c), class should be data_class.

The error message tells you that the class option is not present in the StatusType. This is mostly used in the EntityType.
In addition, there is no option choise_label because there is a small typo choice_label with "c". ;) happened..
You can find a list of types here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html
I doubt whether there is also a StatusType, I think you were referring to your class name when you named it!?
What should be the label? The name that is defined in another class, i.e. from another entity? If so, then I'll have to research it myself, I don't know that well yet, but I hope I could still help.
here is an example of a select fields from my code:
->add('whitelister', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class,
    'choice_label' => 'username',
    'label' => 'Whitelister',
])

